# Swift "override convenience init" not work

Tags: ios, swift, class

I made a class:

```
import UIKit

class SearchBarItem: UIBarButtonItem {
   override convenience init() {
        self.init()
        self.title = "TEST"
    }  
}
```

And It's my View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBtnItem: SearchBarItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

In storyboard I have a navigation bar with a searchBtnItem that Identify Inspector class is SearchBarItem

But searchBtnItem title will not be changed to TEST. 
Whats wrong ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instances loaded from a storyboard don't use `init`, they use `initWithCoder:` so that's the function you need to override and implement with your custom logic.

Comment: Thanks, It's working. but why ?! It doesn't make sense to me!

Comment: everything you configure in the storyboard is provided to the new instance in the decoder so that it can be configured during init, so that's the method that's used, not the plain init